# What is the python command line syntax of "Generate Wizard" in ET GeoWizards in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, shapefile, et-geowizards

> I have the text file formatted as follows

```
ID,Z
1,4.000
366472.538,6353290.852
366477.538,6353289.003
END
ID,Z
2,4.000
366892.538,6353534.939
366894.951,6353537.289
366897.538,6353540.591
366898.814,6353542.289
END
```

The text file is used to create contour polylines by using "ET GeoWizards->Generate(Import/Export)". Because there are heaps of text files and it will involve a lot of repetitive manual work. I am trying to use the Arcpy to automate the process. However, there is no command line syntax for "Generate(Import/Export)" in arcpy.ET toolbox. I also searched http://www.ian-ko.com/ET_GeoWizards/UserGuide/et_geowizards_userguide.htm.

I prefer to use an existing command line syntax to automate the work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There used to be an ArcGIS sample tool called "Create Features from Text File" that would take this line UNGENERATE format and create a feature class from it.

Unless you can re-locate a version of that tool which still works with today's ArcGIS version (which it should) you will need to write it anew using `arcpy.da.InsertCursor()`.